# Validation of value in XML File

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to validate a username check box to see if the value entered exists in an XML file.

On button click, it should check if the name entered exists within the XML file and then proceed, if not the message box should appear.

The current code shows that the txt_Username.Text = Pupil.forename is inaccessible due to its protection level.

On button click:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, Pupil p)
{
    if (txt_Username.Text = Pupil.forename)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Display nw = new Display(theClass);
        nw.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot Find username");
}
```

Pupil Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PassingData
{
    public class Pupil
    {
        private string forename;
        private int score;

        public Pupil(string forename, int score)
        {
            this.forename = forename;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public Pupil()
        {
            this.forename = "Unknown";
        }

        public string Forename
        {
            get { return forename; }
            set { forename = value; }
        }

        public int Score
        {
            get { return score; }
            set { score = value; }
        }

        override public string ToString()
        {
            string output = forename + "\t" + score;
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPupil xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Pupil>
    <Forename>Andy</Forename>
    <Score>0</Score>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Forename>Bob</Forename>
    <Score>10</Score>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Forename>Carl</Forename>
    <Score>20</Score>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Forename>Dave</Forename>
    <Score>30</Score>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Forename>Eric</Forename>
    <Score>40</Score>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Forename>Frank</Forename>
    <Score>50</Score>
  </Pupil>
</ArrayOfPupil>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 'forename' is a private variable
2. `Pupil` is not a Static Class
3. You need to create an instance of `Pupil` and use `Forename` property  instead.

   i.e 
    `Pupil.Forename` is NOT Allowed on a non-static class. 
     Instead

   Pupil objPupil = new Pupil(); 
    var myForeName = objPupil.Forename;
4. In your `If` statement there is only one `=`.
5. Default Button click handler/delegate cannot have the extra parameter `Pupil p`.

Comment: so change forename to public?

What about the static class?

Comment: @MattMeadows: You cannot access a not static member directly without creating an instance.

Comment: @MattMeadows: i.e Pupil.Forename is NOT Allowed on a non-static class. Instead do 'Pupil objPupil = new Pupil(); var myForeName = objPupil.Forename;'.

Comment: Oh I understand now thankyou!

There is 1 more issue, i have an error:

No overload for 'btnNext_Click' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'

Comment: @MattMeadows: That is because you pass a extra parameter `Pupil p` in the Button Click Handler. Removing it would fix your error.

Comment: Ah! Totally missed that sorry!

It now allows the app to load, however doesn't show the next window on Next click, even when the name entered is correct

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27059/discussion-between-jacob-aloysious-and-matt-meadows)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are referencing "forename" (a private field) but should be referencing "Forename" (a public property).
2. You are referencing "Pupil.forename" but should be referencing "p.Forename".
3. As @MattMeadows mentioned, "==" should be used when checking for equality, not "=".

I also recommend auto properties for just setting and getting values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx.

Ex:

```
public string Forename { get; set; }
```